# is pip missing from the strawberry installer?

Tags: windows, apache, pip, strawberry-perl

I recently installed strawberry perl, to get gitweb running with apache on a windows server.

I have done this before by following a tutorial, found here: http://www.aptest.com/atm2/documentation/latest/readme/apache-windows.html#s-3

summary up to the problem:

> 1 Install perl from http://www.strawberryperl.com
>
> 2 Install Apache
>
> 3 Install mod_perl
>
> > Save http://downloads.aptest.com/sperl/setup_spmp as setup_spmp.pl on your system.
> >     Execute setup_spmp.pl

*the pl file is just a script for locating apache and running "pip"*

Here I run into problems, that I did not have the last time I tried this.

> **'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,**
>   **operable program or batch file.**

Have pip been removed from the strawberry installer? - if so what replaces it?
How do I use strawberry perl with apache on windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Strawberry Perl did you install - the latest (5.26.1.1)?

pip was included in earlier versions of Strawberry Perl, but no longer seems to be included: you can see the list of installed distributions in the release notes (http://strawberryperl.com/release-notes/5.26.1.1-64bit.html).

pip is quite old - it hasn't seen a release since 2010 - so the Strawberry Perl folks may have dropped it in favour of something else.

If you need pip, you can try installing it from CPAN:

```
CPAN install pip
```